# MySQL: Error in MySQL Insert Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL. Here is my query:

```
insert into 'JsonData' values(1,'Article_Type', 'Obama Care', 'Obama care is a system', '2014-2-18', 'www.cnn.com', 'a12as%6adj*&^asah*^')
```

This generates the below error:

```
     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''JsonData' 
values(1,'Article_Type', 'Obama Care', 'Obama care is a system', '201' at line 1
```

Following is the table structure:

[image]

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: You should not be sinlge-quoting the table name `JsonData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for quotes:

```
insert into JsonData values(1,'Article_Type', 'Obama Care', 'Obama care is a system', '2014-2-18', 'www.cnn.com', 'a12as%6adj*&^asah*^')
```

However, you can use back ticks if you want (Useful if the table name is some sort of reserved keyword):

```
insert into `JsonData` values(1,'Article_Type', 'Obama Care', 'Obama care is a system', '2014-2-18', 'www.cnn.com', 'a12as%6adj*&^asah*^')
```